# I want to delete values from a column corresponding to values starting with a particular string in another column

Tags: python, pandas, drop

Remove the values in column titled “LogKOW” corresponding to the values starting with V-Mey_NA in the column titled “CAS”.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please take the time to read this post on [how to provide a great pandas example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples) as well as how to provide a [minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and revise your question accordingly. These tips on how to ask a good question may also be useful.

Comment: Please provide some sample data.

Comment: https://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/machine-learning-databases/00511/

Answer (score 0):

I guess this will work

```
for index in df.index:
    if(df['CAS'][index].find('V-Mey_NA') != -1):
        df['LogKOW'][index] = np.nan
```

Comment: Maybe it would be better to use `.startswith('V-Mey_NA')` instead of `.find('V-Mey_NA') != -1`.

Comment: I did this and it worked:

`(c = 0
for i in df['CAS']:
    c +=1 
    if i[0:8] == 'V-Mey_NA':
        df['LogKOW'][c] = np.NaN

df)`

Answer (score 0):

This might help in removing the values

```
x = df1["CAS"].str.startswith("V-Mey_NA")
n = np.arange(0,1058,1)
df1.drop(n[x])
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this instead

```
import numpy as np
df['LogKOW'] = np.where(df.CAS.str.startswith('V-Mey_NA'),np.NaN,df['LogKOW'])
```